# HERE Transit APi (modes)

Tags: here-api

I have a problem with the HERE Transit API. When I try to receive only subway mode nearby stations, I use the following request:

`https://transit.cit.api.here.com/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json?center=40.418969%2C%20-3.700698&radius=1000&modes=Subway&app_id=my app id&app_code=my app codeg&max=3`

But i obtain this response:

`{"Res":{"serviceUrl":"https://transit.cit.api.here.com/transit/v3/stations/by_geocoord.json","Message":{"code":"GW0006","level":"E","text":"'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"}}}`

Anyone knows why? I'm not putting any int in `modes`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the API reference, the *modes* filter (bus, subway, ferry, ...) is available for routing operations, e.g. when you request public transit routes between coordinates. See **[Public Transit Routing](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/resource-routing.html)** resource.

However, the endpoint to find nearby stations given a location does not support the *modes* filter. See API reference for **[Nearby Stations by Geocoord](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/resource-search-geocoord.html)**. While such a filter would have been useful here as well, it is not a bug. That said, since the objects in the response of the Nearby Stations API do specify their *mode*, I would suggest to do the filtering client side.

Comment: Many thanks, well...i will have to wait..until Here fix the problem.

Comment: @alamoalberto95 this is actually not a bug, the fact is that the Nearby Stations search does not support this filter, so you have to filter client-side at the moment if you want to provide this feature to your customers.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation, it states that "***The transit modes allow you to specify (using the modes request parameter) various types of vehicles that you wish to be included in the transit routing results.***"

Basically, filter by modes is supported only for transit routing api and not for [station search by geocoordinates](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/resource-search-geocoord.html).